# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class failing on create

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have looked at other questions and tried their solutions but the error persists.

Also, this is my first iOS project so please explain like I'm five >.<

Ok, so I have a diary entry entity, looking like such:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DiaryEntry: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var text: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var extra: String
@NSManaged var backup: NSNumber
}
```

as well, i have a DAO file like this (abridged)
     import Foundation
     import CoreData

```
 class coreDataDao : NSManagedObject, DiaryDAO{
 func createEntry(title:String,text:String,date:NSDate,backup:NSNumber,extra:String){
  let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DiaryEntry", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! DiaryEntry
    newItem.title=title
    newItem.text=text
    newItem.date=date
    newItem.extra=extra
    newItem.backup=backup.integerValue
}
}
```

and finally, called in my viewcontroller, i have this function:

```
  let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
  func jTest(){
    var dao = coreDataDao()
    dao.createEntry("a title",text:"some text", date: NSDate(), backup: 2, extra: "extras")    
}
```

However when the code runs, I get the following error:

```
MyApp[9786:438760] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'MyAppName.coreDataDao' 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Ive been trying things all day, including most of the SO solutions regarding this error but I can't get it going. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be dealing with ManagedObjectContext. I was atempting to generate it in my DAO file, when it needed to be passed from the ViewController.

DAO

```
 class func createEntry(title:String,context:NSManagedObjectContext)->DiaryEntry{

    if let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DiaryEntry", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? DiaryEntry{
```

and viewcontroller

```
coreDataDao.createEntry("a title",context: self.managedObjectContext!)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Maybe your backup or backup.integer or any other assigned value is nil. Please debug to check.

Comment: You can see how I am passing it, it is hardcoded. perhaps the date object. Debugging now.

Comment: interesting... so I commented out everything in the DOA file and replaced it with println to debug the data. Data was exactly as expected. However, the error persisted.... the fatal error is gone, but the core data error is still there. I didnt realise there are 2 errors in the readout...

Comment: What is DiaryDAO? Why you are inheriting coreDataDao from NSManagedObject?

Comment: it is implementing a protocol. Our frontend guru set it up and is getting me to do the DB ground work

Comment: change  class coreDataDao : NSManagedObject, DiaryDAO to class coreDataDao : DiaryDAO and then tell me.

Comment: I immediately get the error /CoreDataDao.swift:30:31: Use of unresolved identifier 'managedObjectContext'

Comment: For some reason, DiaryEntry is nil. If I do import DiaryEntry it is not found. I dont think it is added to the project for some reason...